# Implementing Dropdown for MultiLine D3 graph

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am attempting to implement a multiline d3 graph that has a dropdown that selects and highlights the line the user picks. For some reason, it is not highlighting the line when a user selects something. Any help would be appreciated!

JS Code:

```
    d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function () {
  return this.each(function () {
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
};

let height2 = 500,
  width2 = 800,
  margin2 = { top: 25, right: 100, bottom: 35, left: 30 };
innerWidth = width2 - margin2.left - margin2.right;

const svg2 = d3
  .select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width2, height2]);

let selectedCountry;

function updateVisualization() {
  d3.selectAll(".highlight").classed("highlight", false);
  d3.select(`.country[data-country="${selectedCountry}"]`).classed(
    "highlight",
    true
  );
  d3.select(`.country[data-country="${selectedCountry}"]`)
    .node()
    .parentNode.appendChild(
      d3.select(`.country[data-country="${selectedCountry}"]`).node()
    );
}

// Add an event listener to the dropdown select element

d3.tsv("data/state.tsv").then((data) => {
  let timeParse = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

  let countries = new Set();

  for (let d of data) {
    d.Date = timeParse(d.Date);
    d.Value = +d.Value;
    countries.add(d.Location); // push unique values to Set
  }

  const dropdown = document.getElementById("country-select");
  dropdown.addEventListener("change", function () {
    selectedCountry = dropdown.value;
    console.log("Selected country:", selectedCountry);
  });

  let x = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.Date))
    .range([margin2.left, width2 - margin2.right]);

  let y = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.Value))
    .nice() // using extent because values are less than 0
    .range([height2 - margin2.bottom, margin2.top]);

  var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

  // Y Axis first
  svg2
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin2.left},0)`)
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(-innerWidth).tickFormat(formatPercent));

  // X Axis second because we want it to be placed on top
  svg2
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height2 - margin2.top})`)
    .call(
      d3
        .axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(3))
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b '%y"))
        .scale(x)
    );

  let line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d) => x(d.Date))
    .y((d) => y(d.Value));

  // looping through set
  for (let country of countries) {
    //.filter filters data in D3
    let countryData = data.filter((d) => d.Location === country);

    let g = svg2
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "country")
      .on("mouseover", function () {
        // set/remove highlight class
        // highlight class defined in html
        d3.selectAll(".highlight").classed("highlight", false);
        var sel = d3.select(this).classed("highlight", true);
        sel.moveToFront();
      });

    // AZ selected in blue on load of page
    if (country === selectedCountry) {
      g.classed("highlight", true);
    }

    g.append("path")
      .datum(countryData) // datum is a single result from data
      .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
      .attr("d", line)
      .style("fill", "none");

    // find position of last piece to position end of line labels
    let lastEntry = countryData[countryData.length - 1];

    g.append("text")
      .text(country)
      .attr("x", x(lastEntry.Date))
      .attr("y", y(lastEntry.Value))
      .attr("dx", "5px") // shifting attribute in svg
      .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
      .attr("fill", "#ffffff");
  }

  svg2
    .append("line")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-opacity", 0.7)
    .style("stroke-dasharray", "5, 3")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .attr("x1", x.range()[0])
    .attr("x2", x.range()[1])
    .attr("y1", 318)
    .attr("y2", 318);

  let g = svg2
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "country")
    .on("mouseover", function () {
      d3.selectAll(".highlight").classed("highlight", false);
      d3.select(this).classed("highlight", true);
      this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
});
```

I am not sure what is happening. It seems to be able to select the country and read that in, but for some reason is not highlighting the line like I would have expected it to.

Some HTML/CSS Code

```
<h3 class="chart-title">Percent Change in Mobility Rates By State</h3>
      <h4 class="chart-subtitle">As a Percent of 2019 Mobility Data</h4>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <select id="country-select">
          <option value="DC">DC</option>
          <option value="MD">MD</option>
          <option value="VA">VA</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="charts" id="chart"></div>
      <p class="datasource">
        Data from the US Department of Transportation's
        <a
          href="https://data.bts.gov/Research-and-Statistics/Trips-by-Distance/w96p-f2qv"
          >Daily Trips By Distance</a
        >
        dataset.
      </p>


.country {
            cursor: default;
            }
            .country path {
            stroke-width: 1.5;
            opacity: 0.75;
            }
            .highlight path {
            stroke: steelblue;
            opacity: 1;
            }
            .highlight text {
            fill: steelblue;
            }
```

Sample of states.tsv

```
Location    Date    Value
AK  29-Dec-19   -0.03                       
AK  5-Jan-20    0.03                        
AK  12-Jan-20   0.05                        
AK  19-Jan-20   0.04                        
AK  26-Jan-20   0.02                        
AK  2-Feb-20    0.00                        
AK  9-Feb-20    0.04                        
AK  16-Feb-20   0.10                        
AK  23-Feb-20   0.11                        
AK  1-Mar-20    -0.06                       
AK  8-Mar-20    -0.08                       
AK  15-Mar-20   -0.31                       
AK  22-Mar-20   -0.49                       
AK  29-Mar-20   -0.49                       
AK  5-Apr-20    -0.47                       
AK  12-Apr-20   -0.38                       
AK  19-Apr-20   -0.34                       
AK  26-Apr-20   -0.37                       
AK  3-May-20    -0.37                       
AK  10-May-20   -0.33                       
AK  17-May-20   -0.27                       
AK  24-May-20   -0.40                       
AK  31-May-20   -0.41                       
AK  7-Jun-20    -0.37                       
AK  14-Jun-20   -0.40                       
AK  21-Jun-20   -0.45                       
AK  28-Jun-20   -0.48                       
AK  5-Jul-20    -0.51                       
AK  12-Jul-20   -0.54                       
AK  19-Jul-20   -0.55                       
AK  26-Jul-20   -0.54                       
AK  2-Aug-20    -0.51                       
AK  9-Aug-20    -0.46                       
AK  16-Aug-20   -0.49                       
AK  23-Aug-20   -0.54                       
AK  30-Aug-20   -0.54                       
AK  6-Sep-20    -0.53                       
AK  13-Sep-20   -0.50                       
AK  20-Sep-20   -0.50                       
AK  27-Sep-20   -0.47                       
AK  4-Oct-20    -0.54                       
AK  11-Oct-20   -0.54                       
AK  18-Oct-20   -0.52                       
AK  25-Oct-20   -0.54                       
AK  1-Nov-20    -0.37                       
AK  8-Nov-20    -0.52                       
AK  15-Nov-20   -0.53                       
AK  22-Nov-20   -0.54                       
AK  29-Nov-20   -0.54                       
AK  6-Dec-20    -0.56                       
AK  13-Dec-20   -0.58                       
AK  20-Dec-20   -0.58                       
AK  27-Dec-20   -0.26                       
AK  3-Jan-21    -0.18                       
AK  10-Jan-21   -0.18                       
AK  17-Jan-21   -0.10                       
AK  24-Jan-21   -0.11                       
AK  31-Jan-21   -0.01                       
AK  7-Feb-21    0.01                        
AK  14-Feb-21   0.01                        
AK  21-Feb-21   -0.04                       
AK  28-Feb-21   0.13                        
AK  7-Mar-21    0.08                        
AK  14-Mar-21   0.45                        
AK  21-Mar-21   0.86                        
AK  28-Mar-21   0.75                        
AK  4-Apr-21    0.67                        
AK  11-Apr-21   0.54                        
AK  18-Apr-21   0.44                        
AK  25-Apr-21   0.36                        
AK  2-May-21    0.37                        
AK  9-May-21    0.32                        
AK  16-May-21   0.15                        
AK  23-May-21   0.30                        
AK  30-May-21   0.36                        
AK  6-Jun-21    0.30                        
AK  13-Jun-21   0.44                        
AK  20-Jun-21   0.41                        
AK  27-Jun-21   0.52                        
AK  4-Jul-21    0.54                        
AK  11-Jul-21   0.60                        
AK  18-Jul-21   0.67                        
AK  25-Jul-21   0.67                        
AK  1-Aug-21    0.53                        
AK  8-Aug-21    0.37                        
AK  15-Aug-21   0.43                        
AK  22-Aug-21   0.66                        
AK  29-Aug-21   0.66                        
AK  5-Sep-21    0.60                        
AK  12-Sep-21   0.44                        
AK  19-Sep-21   0.47                        
AK  26-Sep-21   0.51                        
AK  3-Oct-21    0.61                        
AK  10-Oct-21   0.64                        
AK  17-Oct-21   0.54                        
AK  24-Oct-21   0.53                        
AK  31-Oct-21   0.14                        
AK  7-Nov-21    0.47                        
AK  14-Nov-21   0.54                        
AK  21-Nov-21   0.58                        
AK  28-Nov-21   0.54                        
AK  5-Dec-21    0.64                        
AK  12-Dec-21   0.76                        
AK  19-Dec-21   0.90                        
AK  26-Dec-21   0.27                        
AK  2-Jan-22    0.32                        
AK  9-Jan-22    0.23                        
AK  16-Jan-22   0.18                        
AK  23-Jan-22   0.22                        
AK  30-Jan-22   0.08                        
AL  29-Dec-19   -0.11                       
AL  5-Jan-20    -0.06                       
AL  12-Jan-20   0.00                        
AL  19-Jan-20   0.00                        
AL  26-Jan-20   0.01                        
AL  2-Feb-20    0.00                        
AL  9-Feb-20    0.07                        
AL  16-Feb-20   0.05                        
AL  23-Feb-20   0.08                        
AL  1-Mar-20    0.05                        
AL  8-Mar-20    0.01                        
AL  15-Mar-20   -0.21                       
AL  22-Mar-20   -0.35                       
AL  29-Mar-20   -0.36                       
AL  5-Apr-20    -0.36                       
AL  12-Apr-20   -0.34                       
AL  19-Apr-20   -0.34                       
AL  26-Apr-20   -0.31                       
AL  3-May-20    -0.26                       
AL  10-May-20   -0.22                       
AL  17-May-20   -0.19                       
AL  24-May-20   -0.29                       
AL  31-May-20   -0.25                       
AL  7-Jun-20    -0.23                       
AL  14-Jun-20   -0.23                       
AL  21-Jun-20   -0.25                       
AL  28-Jun-20   -0.27                       
AL  5-Jul-20    -0.27                       
AL  12-Jul-20   -0.29                       
AL  19-Jul-20   -0.31                       
AL  26-Jul-20   -0.32                       
AL  2-Aug-20    -0.27                       
AL  9-Aug-20    -0.28                       
AL  16-Aug-20   -0.26                       
AL  23-Aug-20   -0.34                       
AL  30-Aug-20   -0.35                       
AL  6-Sep-20    -0.32                       
AL  13-Sep-20   -0.31                       
AL  20-Sep-20   -0.31                       
AL  27-Sep-20   -0.26                       
AL  4-Oct-20    -0.27                       
AL  11-Oct-20   -0.25                       
AL  18-Oct-20   -0.16                       
AL  25-Oct-20   -0.16                       
AL  1-Nov-20    -0.07                       
AL  8-Nov-20    -0.11                       
AL  15-Nov-20   -0.11                       
AL  22-Nov-20   -0.18                       
AL  29-Nov-20   -0.13                       
AL  6-Dec-20    -0.21                       
AL  13-Dec-20   -0.21                       
AL  20-Dec-20   -0.24                       
AL  27-Dec-20   0.00                        
AL  3-Jan-21    -0.03                       
AL  10-Jan-21   0.00                        
AL  17-Jan-21   0.05                        
AL  24-Jan-21   0.03                        
AL  31-Jan-21   0.07                        
AL  7-Feb-21    0.07                        
AL  14-Feb-21   0.05                        
AL  21-Feb-21   0.12                        
AL  28-Feb-21   0.11                        
AL  7-Mar-21    0.12                        
AL  14-Mar-21   0.23                        
AL  21-Mar-21   0.50                        
AL  28-Mar-21   0.50                        
AL  4-Apr-21    0.52                        
AL  11-Apr-21   0.62                        
AL  18-Apr-21   0.39                        
AL  25-Apr-21   0.19                        
AL  2-May-21    0.18                        
AL  9-May-21    0.15                        
AL  16-May-21   0.10                        
AL  23-May-21   0.21                        
AL  30-May-21   0.17                        
AL  6-Jun-21    0.17                        
AL  13-Jun-21   0.18                        
AL  20-Jun-21   0.24                        
AL  27-Jun-21   0.29                        
AL  4-Jul-21    0.31                        
AL  11-Jul-21   0.26                        
AL  18-Jul-21   0.26                        
AL  25-Jul-21   0.22                        
AL  1-Aug-21    0.16                        
AL  8-Aug-21    0.18                        
AL  15-Aug-21   0.18                        
AL  22-Aug-21   0.32                        
AL  29-Aug-21   0.23                        
AL  5-Sep-21    0.25                        
AL  12-Sep-21   0.22                        
AL  19-Sep-21   0.22                        
AL  26-Sep-21   0.18                        
AL  3-Oct-21    0.28                        
AL  10-Oct-21   0.30                        
AL  17-Oct-21   0.27                        
AL  24-Oct-21   0.27                        
AL  31-Oct-21   0.20                        
AL  7-Nov-21    0.22                        
AL  14-Nov-21   0.25                        
AL  21-Nov-21   0.35                        
AL  28-Nov-21   0.23                        
AL  5-Dec-21    0.38                        
AL  12-Dec-21   0.39                        
AL  19-Dec-21   0.52                        
AL  26-Dec-21   0.22                        
AL  2-Jan-22    0.18                        
AL  9-Jan-22    0.09                        
AL  16-Jan-22   0.06                        
AL  23-Jan-22   0.05                        
AL  30-Jan-22   0.10
```

Comment: Please take the time and post a minimal reproducible code example. There is an inline code editor to split html, js and css so others can work on your problem.